# NonUniqueResultException thrown when using spring jpa "findtop"

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring JPA, and NonUniqueResultException throw when I use "findTop" keyword

Java source:

```
Optional<ClassA> findTopByXXXOrderByIdDesc(String xxx);
```

Then get the exception:

> exceptionType = org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException exception = result returns more than one elements; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: result returns more than one elements

Any one know what happen?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: for my understanding, even though will returned more than one result, however, as I used "findTop", so Spring JPA will help me to select top one of the result

Comment: problem resolved, because the version should at least 1.7.1.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please check the version of your Spring Data JPA. Note that Top and First are available since 1.7.1.RELEASE.

Answer (score -1):

You tried to retrieve the result as 'query.getSingleResult()' hoping you will get only one result. whereas your query returned more than one result. That's why this exception occur.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: for my understanding, even though will returned more than one result, however, as I used "findTop", so Spring JPA will help me to select top one of the result